# How can you call a second function while using a lambda function in an .apply() call in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, lambda

I am wondering how to convert a for-loop into a .apply() method in Pandas.
I'm trying to iterate over one column of a dataframe (df1) and return matches from subsets of a second dataframe (df2). I have a function to do the matching (Matching), and also a function to select the right subset from df2 (Filter). I want to know if it's possible to use Pandas' .apply() method to call both functions.

I have worked out how to do this as a for-loop (see below), and it  seems that I can do it with a list comprehension by creating a complete function first (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44412042/can-i-call-a-function-inside-a-lambda-expression-in-python)) but I'm having trouble doing it via the Pandas .apply() method and a lambda expression.

```
## Here is my Filter, which selects titles from df2 for one year 
## either side of a target year
def Filter (year):
    years = [year-1, year, year+1]
    return df2[df2.year.isin(years)].title

# Here is my matching routine, it uses the process method from
# fuzzywuzzy
def Matcher(title, choices):
    title_match, percent_match, match3 = process.extractOne(title, 
choices, scorer=fuzz.token_sort_ratio)
    return title_match

# Here is my solution using a for-loop
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    targets = Filter(row.year)
    df1.loc[index,'return_match'] = Matcher(row.title, targets)

# Here's my attempt with a lambda function
df1['new_col'] = df1.title.apply(lambda x: Matcher(x, 
Filter(df1.year)))
```

When I use the lambda function, what appears to happen is that the Filter function is only called on the very first iteration of the .apply() method, so every title is matched to that first filtered set. Is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO JP.
I see a problem in this line:

```py
# Here's my attempt with a lambda function
df1['new_col'] = df1.title.apply(lambda x: Matcher(x, Filter(df1.year)))
```

you call `Filter` on all of your DataFrame column `year`, while as your for loop solution you want to call it on just the year of that row. so I recommend using apply on rows like this:

```py
df1['new_col'] = df1.apply(lambda row: Matcher(row.title, Filter(row.year)), axis=1)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: That was super helpful, I used it and it totally worked. Sorry for forgetting to thank you.